# Filter questions by watched tags

Tags: discussion, support, tags, filtering

The new site design includes "Watched Tags" instead of "Favorite Tags." Watching tags highlights them in the list of questions; is there a way to filter the questions such that no questions that do not contain a watched tag show up?

Comment: Do you mean when looking at /questions or the home page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible if you opt into [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179). Just click the filter dropdown and select "My watched tags":

> [image]

With the other options available, you can have the questions sorted however you want.